# Performance of Bellman–Ford shortest path algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, shortest-path

I implemented the solution of Bellman - Ford algorithm with a queue and I compared its performance with the Dijkstra algorithm. They were pretty close and that was a surprise for me because the complexity of Bellman - Ford is O(NM). I know that the complexity is for the worst case, but still the result was surprising. I searched for some information about Bellman - Ford and I found only this statement in Sedgewick, Algorithms in Java "on real networks the Bellman–Ford algorithm typically runs in linear time".
Could you give me an explanation of the Bellman - Ford algorithm performance behaviour?

Comment: If you're looking for good implementations of both algorithms in c++ see boosts graph lib. 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html

Comment: Code is here: https://github.com/boostorg/graph/blob/develop/include/boost/graph/bellman_ford_shortest_paths.hpp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a paper on it that's pretty straight forward ([PDF Link](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~musser/gp/algorithm-concepts/bellman-ford-screen.pdf)).

> The complexity of the Bellman-Ford
>   algorithm depends on the number of
>   edge examinations, or relaxation calls.
>   (Note this is different from
>   relaxation steps which refer to the
>   actual changes performed.)
>   As mentioned, the number of relaxation
>   calls can be smaller than |V ||E| with
>   the BGL implementation. In fact, it is
>   much smaller than |V ||E| in the
>   average case.

It lists pseudocode and further analysis as well.